# Shift menu down when dropdown menu opens

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm building my website [here](http://www.marcellogiovenco.com) and I would like my left menu to be shifted down when the dropdown menu opens so that they don't overlap. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PROJECTS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
          <li><a href="#napoli" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">NAPOLI</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portraits" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">PORTRAITS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">BIO</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blablabla" data-toggle="tab">BLABLABLA</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone could help?
Thanks!

Javascript problem with fadein fadeout

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".nav > li > a").bind("click", function(){
          $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
          $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn(); 
       }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is override the css for the class dropdown-menu.
What I did in the inspector was under `.dropdown-menu` remove the styles

```
position:absolute;
float:left;


.dropdown-menu {
    position:relative !important; <-- or static
    float:none !important;
}
```

This will make the drop down menu have its own space and not hover over the rest of your menu. But something is also wrong with your toggle. It seems to be broken. The markup looks fine. Did you tamper with the javascript or something?

So for your javascript problem, it is a little hard to test it but try this:
Revised: Based On http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $('.dropdown-menu',this).fadeIn();
   });

   $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
      $('.dropdown-menu',this).fadeOut();
   });
}
```

Comment: The toggle is fine. Are you using Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @floor I used javascript to make the submenu fade in and out, but need to fix this. Any solution accepted :)
About your solution: it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Post your javascript. I said in the inspector I did these and it changed the menu how you wanted it.

Comment: @Stephn_R It does not toggle fine did you go to his website? I am working with the code from his website, and if you  look at the inspector and turn of position absolute and float left from .dropdown-menu, the menu works as he wants it.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav > li > a").bind("click", function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut();
     $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();
    });
});`

This makes the submenu fade in and out and it works fine. 
Problem is that when I click again on the already open menu item (e.g. Projects) it fades out and in again instead of ignoring the command.

Comment: @floor your code is now working setting position to static. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marcello Yeah I know it works. I will also help you with that javascript just give me a min

Comment: The javascript you proposed doesn't seem to work... it doesn't fade and the submenu disappear when clicked.

Comment: @Marcello Updated again.

Comment: Now it's better but the dropdown menu closes also when the same submenu items (or "Projects") are being clicked

Comment: can you put it on your live site so I can see

Comment: It seems to be working to me, whats the problem? You don't want the drop down to close if you click on other links besides "projects" ?, It should close anyways if those are real links, they will send the user to a new page.

Comment: They are not "real links" but they point to other parts of the page so the menu basically doesn't change but only the content on the right side of the page does. That's why it's important that the menu stays open. Kinda what happens here [link](http://www.christopherandersonphoto.com/)

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by overriding the bootstrap defaults for absolute positioning and dropdown toggling:

```
.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: 200px;
}
```

And then to keep the menu open, a little bit of JS:

```
$('#myTabDrop1').on('click', function(e) {
    // Remove active tab
    $('#myNavbar').find('nav > li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').addClass('open');
});
```

**New HTML**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1">PROJECTS</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#napoli" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">NAPOLI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portraits" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">PORTRAITS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">BIO</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blablabla" data-toggle="tab">BLABLABLA</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ordk043e/8/)

Comment: Thanks this shifts the menu down, but when I click on any submenu items it comes back up and overlap it. Any idea?
I updated the website and yes I use Bootstrap 3.

Comment: So you would like to dropdown menu to stay open? Until when?

Comment: Until I click either on any other menu item (not submenu items) or the title. But that's already accomplished, the problem is just that when I click on submenu items your solution stops working...

Comment: As, so if a submenu item is selected, you want the dropdown to remain open?

Comment: is this not what I posted?

Comment: @Stephn_R your solution with js also works fine now that I tried again. Only thing is that it behaves weird when clicking again on Projects. A solution could be to disable "Projects" once opened? Any idea how to toggle the class to .disabled?

Comment: To do that, we just need to change addClass to toggleClass. I updated the JSFiddle and the answer

Comment: @Stephn_R it doesn't change if I use toggleClass, clicking on Projects, if already open, makes the submenu to overlap the main one.
Is there a way to disable the link Project once already open?

Comment: So you want to keep the menu alive even when it's active and even when you click on the active tab?

Comment: Yes, "Projects" should not respond to click if opened. And only close if other links (NOT in the submenu) are clicked.

Comment: i updated the code. This time, we are removing the dropdown support entirely via the Dropdown classes and including our own custom JS to handle this.